# border radius inside of border shorthand CSS

Tags: css, border

Could you include the value for the `border-radius` inside of the `border`? Something like `border: 1px solid #ccc 4px`?

Comment: No. The shorthand was finalized before `border-radius` was added to the spec

Comment: note that border-radius is also a shorthand